# javascript id into css with background-scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I used google translate so do not ask why.

I'm writing a script and try to iclude a variable (javascript) with  to a css file.

```
<span id="s-map"></span>

{background: url('backgrounds/{<span id="s-map"></span>}/1.jpg;');}
```

Problem is I use background scroll and try with a variable to complete the path to the background images /

script:

( the script is called in a game by the url, the page details will be retrieve from the game and this is the origin of the var "mapname")

actuel map in the game = de_dolls | so mapname= "de_dolls";

```
function Game Details (mapname) {
document.getElementById ("s-map") innerHTML = mapname.;
}

Url ('backgrounds / {<span id="s-map"> </ span>} / 1.jpg;');}
```

and now i try to become this result:

```
Url ('backgrounds/de_dolls/1.jpg;');}
```

i hope any body have unterstand the system....

Here are the full script parts

Javascript.js

```
function GameDetails( servername, serverurl, mapname, maxplayers, steamid, gamemode ) {
    document.getElementById( "s-name" ).innerHTML = servername;
    document.getElementById( "s-map" ).innerHTML = mapname;
    document.getElementById( "s-mode" ).innerHTML = gamemode;
    document.getElementById( "s-max" ).innerHTML = maxplayers;
}
```

index.php

```
<div id="background-scroll">
<div id="bg1"></div><!-- BG 1 -->
<div id="bg2"></div><!-- BG 2 -->
<div id="bg3"></div><!-- BG 3 -->
<div id="bg4"></div><!-- BG 4 -->
<div id="bg5"></div><!-- BG 5 -->
<div id="bg6"></div><!-- BG 6 -->
</div>
```

style.css

```
#background-scroll { width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; z-index:-10;}

#bg1 {background: url('backgrounds/*MAPNAME*/1.jpg;'); background-size: 100% auto; background-size: cover; width: 100%; height: 100%;}

#bg2 {background: url('backgrounds/*MAPNAME*/2.jpg; ?>'); background-size: 100% auto; background-size: cover; width: 100%; height: 100%;}

#bg3 {background: url('backgrounds/*MAPNAME*/3.jpg; ?>'); background-size: 100% auto; background-size: cover; width: 100%; height: 100%;}

#bg4 {background: url('backgrounds/*MAPNAME*/4.jpg; ?>'); background-size: 100% auto; background-size: cover; width: 100%; height: 100%;}

#bg5 {background: url('backgrounds/*MAPNAME*/5.jpg; ?>'); background-size: 100% auto; background-size: cover; width: 100%; height: 100%;}

#bg6 {background: url('backgrounds/*MAPNAME*/6.jpg; ?>'); background-size: 100% auto; background-size: cover; width: 100%; height: 100%;}
```

THANKS AHEAD when anybody have questions feel free and comment :)

Comment: Even *Google Translate* makes Typos ...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change an external stylesheet via Javascript but you can change the styling of elements. 
Here is a fiddle showing you how to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/wg4MG/

HTML:

```
 //Note I added class="maps"
<div id="background-scroll">
    <div id="bg1" class="maps"></div>
    <!-- BG 1 -->
    <div id="bg2" class="maps"></div>
    <!-- BG 2 -->
    <div id="bg3" class="maps"></div>
    <!-- BG 3 -->
    <div id="bg4" class="maps"></div>
    <!-- BG 4 -->
    <div id="bg5" class="maps"></div>
    <!-- BG 5 -->
    <div id="bg6" class="maps"></div>
    <!-- BG 6 -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
//Removed background styling from #bg's
#background-scroll {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index:-10;
}
#bg1 {
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#bg2 {
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#bg3 {

    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#bg4 {
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#bg5 {
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#bg6 {
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

JS:

```
function GameDetails(servername, serverurl, mapname, maxplayers, steamid, gamemode) {
    document.getElementById("s-name").innerHTML = servername;
    document.getElementById("s-map").innerHTML = mapname;
    document.getElementById("s-mode").innerHTML = gamemode;
    document.getElementById("s-max").innerHTML = maxplayers;


}
//This function will change the background image to the url with *MAPNAME*
function changeBackground(mapname){
    var maps = document.getElementsByClassName("maps");

    for(var i =0; i < maps.length; i++)
    {
        maps[i].style.background = "url('backgrounds/"+mapname+"/2.jpg')";
    }
}
```

Comment: my bad, changed it from `getElementsByClass` to `getElementsByClassName`. Try now, you will have to call the function when you want to change the background.

Comment: thanks <3 have you skype or something i think i am toooooo stupid for that --- hmmmmhmmh